# Why are Aleph Cardinal Numbers "strictly increasing"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

perhaps my title isn't very clear, I'll try to be more precise:
The definition I'm using is that (for the "successor" step of the recursion) $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the smallest cardinal which is strictly greater that $\aleph_{\alpha}$.
I take this to mean that $\aleph_{\alpha+1} = \inf \{$cardinals $C$ such that there exists a one sided injection, but not a bijection between $C$ and $ \aleph_{\alpha} \}$

What I can't figure out is how to show that with this definition, $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ indeed remains strictly greater than $\aleph_{\alpha}$, ie there is no bijection between $\aleph_{\alpha}, \aleph_{\alpha+1}$.
I know that there exists the generalized continuity hypothesis which would settle this question, but I'm thinking it is probably overkill and that I should be able to show this some other way, no?
If someone could help me with what is probably a simple reasoning that would be great.

Comment: What's $N$? Is that supposed to be $\aleph$? You can just use `\aleph` for that.

Comment: But that's just the definition, right? ("...smallest cardinal which is *strictly greater*..."). Are you worried that taking an infimum may wreck this? Since ordinals are well-ordered, infimums are minimums, so there is no issue.

Comment: In terms of ordinals, you want to prove $\omega_{\alpha+1}\notin\omega_{\alpha+1}$. All ordinals $\beta$ satisfy $\beta\notin\beta$; indeed, all sets $x$ satisfy $x\notin x$ (but you can prove the special case of ordinals without even using the axiom of regularity, via transfinite induction).

Comment: This uses the Axiom of Choice.  Then we can prove that any set of cardinals is well ordered.  And therefore such a least one exists.  Of course without AC we cannot prove it.

Comment: @GEdgar The ordinals are always well-ordered, by construction. There is no usage of choice there. Choice would be saying that _any_ set is in bijection with an aleph.

Comment: @Sean Eberhard: Yes, I'm worried that the infimum will wreck this.
So if I understand correctly, this is not a problem because I can take a cardinal K not in bijection with $\aleph_{\alpha}$, and then I know that $\{E:=C\subseteq K: C$ is a cardinal not bijective to $\aleph_{\alpha} \}$ is a set, not a class, and then $inf E = \aleph_{\alpha}$, (where I now know that the inf is a minimum because K is well-ordered), correct?

Comment: Even taking the infimum of a (nonempty) class of ordinals is harmless. Maybe read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_cardinal or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment#Initial_ordinal_of_a_cardinal to clarify your thoughts. By the way, your definition of $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ as "the smallest *cardinal* such that..." presupposes the axiom of choice, because AC is equivalent to the statement that the order relation on cardinalities is trichotomous. A more standard definition of $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the cardinality of the smallest *ordinal* of larger cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more accurate to say $\aleph_{\alpha+1} = \min\{\kappa \text{ cardinal } \mid (\exists f \text{ injection }: f:\kappa \to \aleph_\alpha) \land \kappa \not\simeq \aleph_\alpha \}$ so a *minimum* not an infimum (which is also true) because all sets/classes of cardinals (which are sets of ordinals too) have a minimum. In particular $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is *itself* a member of that set of cardinals, so is strictly greater than $\aleph_\alpha$ *by definition*.

Comment: +1. To the OP, this answer is absolutely correct. However, let me supplement it by observing that your concern re: infima is quite justified **once we abandon choice**. Specifically, working in $\mathsf{ZF}$ *(= set theory without choice)*, infima of sets of cardinalities need not exist at all. Even when they do exist, we may see bad behavior. For instance, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is an uncountable set $X$ such that the infimum of the cardinalities of the uncountable subsets of $X$ exists but is just $\aleph_0$. *(Take $X=\mathbb{N}\cup A$ for an **amorphous** set $A$.)*

Comment: @NoahSchweber true enough. But I’m a firm adopter op AC. Well order everything in sight!

Comment: Fair enough :P. I just wanted to confirm to the OP that their instinctual concern does have its place.